# Sheaf cohomology of a cover (please find my mistake)

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

This question will be a bit long because its subject is quite technical.

First some preliminaries: If you have a cover of a space that is open or locally finite and closed you can try to compute sheaf cohomology
of the space from sheaf cohomology of elements of the cover.

One well-known instance of this approach is Leray's theorem:

---

**Theorem**

Assume that $H^{i>0}(U_i;\mathscr{F})=0$ for all elements of the cover $\mathscr{U}=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of the space $X.$ Then there is an isomorphism
$$
   H^*(X;\mathscr{F})\cong H^*_{\mathscr{U}}(\mathscr{F}).
$$

---

There is, however, a finer result which implies Leray's theorem.

---

**Theorem**

Let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a cover of the space $X.$ Then there is an isomorphism
$$
   H^*(X;\mathscr{F})\cong H^*_{\mathrm{Tot}}(C^*(\mathscr{U};\mathscr{G}^*)).
$$
Here $\mathscr{G}^*$ is the Godement resolution of the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ (actually any flasque resolution will do).

---

Now standard methods for the cohomology of the double complex imply the following result:

---

**Theorem**

There is a spectral sequence with converging to $H^*(X;\mathscr{F})$ induced by the column filtration. Its $E_1$ page is isomorphic to

$$ 
E_1=C^*(\mathscr{U};\mathscr{H}_\mathscr{F}^*)
$$
Here $\mathscr{H}_\mathscr{F}^*$ is a local system on the nerve of $\mathscr{U}$ given by $\mathscr{F}$-cohomology of elements $U_I.$

---

Now, what I was trying to do. I tried to compute sheaf cohomology of a space using the spectral sequence above. In my case nerve of a cover is just a 2-simplex.

My goal was to prove that the spectral sequence collapses (not always but in my particular case) at the $E_2$-page. To do this I have used an explicit computation with double complex, which forms the page $E_0$ of the spectral sequence. As a resolution for my sheaf, I used Godement resolution.

Now what I have obtained is clearly wrong, because it seems that the spectral sequence always collapses at the term $E_2$ (without any additional assumptions).

The computation goes like this. Denote the vertices of the nerve by $0,1,2.$ Denote the sheaf for which we are trying to compute by $\mathscr{F}.$ Denote by $\mathscr{G}^i$ the $i$-th term of the Godement resolution for the sheaf $\mathscr{F}.$ And let elements of the cover be denoted by $U_I,$ where $I$ is a set with elements in $\{0,1,2\}.$

Then a generic element of the group $E_0^{0,1}$ looks like $\xi=(\xi_0,\xi_1,\xi_2).$ Here $\xi_i\in \mathscr{G}^1(U_i).$ Now assume that $\xi$ is a cycle with respect to $d_1.$ Then $d_{\check{C}}(\xi)=d_{G}\nu.$ Here $d_G$ is the differential in Godement resolution and $d_{\check{C}}$ is the Čech differential. The element $\nu$ is in $E_0^{1,0}.$

Explicitly the equation $d_{\check{C}}(\xi)=d_{G}\nu$ means that

$$
((\xi_1-\xi_0)\vert_{U_{01}},(\xi_2-\xi_1)\vert_{U_{12}},(\xi_2-\xi_0)\vert_{U_{20}})=\left(\prod_{x\in U_{01}} \nu^{01}_x, \prod_{y\in U_{12}} \nu^{12}_y,\prod_{z\in U_{20}} \nu^{20}_x\right)=d_G \nu
$$

Now to prove that $d_2(\xi)=0$ we need to check that $d_{\check{C}}(\nu)=0.$ By definition we have:

$$
d_{\check{C}}(\nu)=\prod_{x\in U_{012}} (\nu^{12}_x-\nu^{20}_x+\nu^{01}_x)=(\xi_1-\xi_0)\vert_{U_{012}}+(\xi_2-\xi_1)\vert_{U_{012}}-(\xi_2-\xi_0)\vert_{U_{012}}=0\vert_{U_{012}}
$$

Now to prove that the whole $d_1$ is trivial I just need to replace the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ with an appropriate term of the Godement resolution. Then I just repeat the argument above.

What am I getting wrong? It seems that by using similar computations we can prove that the only non-trivial differential in this spectral sequence is always $d_1.$ This is obviously not true.

Comment: I’m not very comfortable with spectral sequences, but isn’t it expected since the functor of global sections is left exact? If $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}^1 \rightarrow \mathcal{G}^2$ is exact, then if $\xi \in \prod_{i=0}^2{\mathcal{G}^1(U_i)}$ is such that $d_1\xi=0$, it means that every $\xi_i$ comes from some element in $\mathcal{F}(U_i)$ and $\nu$ is the Cech differential of that element of $\prod_i{\mathcal{F}(U_i)}$. How does your argument work if you consider $\mathcal{G}^2$ instead of $\mathcal{G}^1$?

Comment: @Mindlack Well, I assumed that since Godement construction is iterative I can just replace $\mathscr{F}$ with $\textrm{coker}(\mathscr{F}\to \mathcal{G}^1).$ Then everything goes through. I think I saw a similar argument in Godement's book

Comment: The notations doesn't seem very clear to me. 1) Are you talking about a cover with only three open subsets ? 2) You seem to computes only $E_2^{0,1}\to E_2^{2,0}$, this isn't the whole differential at $E_2$. 3) You seem to identify $\nu_x^{01}$ and $\xi_1-\xi_0$, but beware : the differential in the Godement resolution are obviously not injectives. I think the last one is the real mistakes but maybe this only me which isn't confortable with your notations.

Comment: I assume that the spectral sequence is coming from a(row or column?) filtration on the total complex associated to the double complex. Could you please setup the notations you are using first? and then write the hypothesis on the cover the page 2 of the spectral sequence you obtain? I think it would be helpful if the question is written more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: @Roland I have edited my question and added more context, thank you for your interest in my question